# Any jQuery Tools guru know how to fix this tooltip issue?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

Such as on http://www.babyfoodratings.com/, the menu bar item uses [jQuery Tools Tooltips](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html), but
when the mouse moves over those menu items, 85% of the time, the tooltip shows up, but the other 15%, nothing will show.
Is there a way to fix it?

(it happens more often in Firefox with Firebug running (I am using a Macbook))

**Update:** there is a new discovery: if I remove the `<a ...>` inside the `<div>` of those tab items, then it works 95%... so somehow just need to find a way to show those icons without the `<a>` tags, and it will work better, but still not 100%...

**Update 2:**  If I make the element that triggers the popup up of the tooltip to be an `<a>`, with a `<span>` inside showing the caption (the CSS sprite), then it works 99%.  Both `<a>` and `<span>` are made to `display: block` (so the `<div>` was changed to `<a>` instead).  Before, it was a `<div>` or even earlier, an `<li>` that triggered the popup of tooltip, and they worked only about 80% of the time.

Comment: even on the plugin page this happens.. so i would just wait for a new version

Comment: you mean its demo page?  which one?  for me it doesn't happen for the demo pages, but it seems like for a more complicated case or maybe a slow CPU or with Firebug running, then it is more likely to happen

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem - tooltips sometimes just won't show.

A solution that now works for me, is to set the 'predelay' value to the tooltip. Values around 150 (in ms) and higher makes the tooltip now working fine in my application.
Maybe this will work also for you.

Edit:

Forgot to say:
In my case, the tooltip always works fine if it's configured without the 'slide' effect. 
With the 'slide' effect, I've got to set the 'predelay' value.